# How to divide all elements of a list and print them all on separate lines?

Tags: python, list, function, for-loop

I'm new to coding and have to make a function that will compute angles. I want to divide 360 by all elements in my list using a for loop and then print them each on a separate line however each time it only divides the last element. How do I fix this?

```
num_sides = [3,4,5,6]

def compute_turn_angle():
    for i in range(len(num_sides)):
        turn_angle = 360 / num_sides[i]
    return turn_angle

print(compute_turn_angle())

#This is what I get:
 60.0

#But this is what I want:
 120
  90
  72
  60
```

Comment: Put a print statement inside the function or return a list of values from a function, because at the moment it only returns the last computed value

Comment: "however each time it only divides the last element." It does every division, but `return` can only happen once, and `return turn_angle` gives back the *individual* value that `turn_angle` had *when the `return` happened*. Please see the linked duplicates for details.

Comment: _[360. / x for x in num_sides]_.

Answer (score 0):

make the changes in a seperate list and return that, while printing, give a parameter value for 'end' attribute of print function.

```
    num_sides = [3,4,5,6]
    
    def compute_turn_angle():
        turn_angle =[]
        for i in range(len(num_sides)):
            turn_angle[i]=(360 / num_sides[i])
        return turn_angle
    
    print(compute_turn_angle(),end='\n')
```

Comment: This will not produce the exact output the OP requested. Have you tested the code?

Comment: There's also no need to use the ugly form `range(len(num_sides))`, just do `for i in range num_sides`

Comment: yes, there are better approach for overall use case also, we don't need a new list, we can update the current one also, but i tried to change minimum  from OPs code

Comment: It's a better approach not to "change the minimum from OPs code" but to demonstrate correct patterns even if more change is necessary. Also, updating the existing list is an anti-pattern and you should never do it.

Comment: i agree, also, just FYI, updating a list whose scope is limited to the function , within the function is not an antipattern, anti pattern would be if i actually update the original input list.

Answer (score 0):

after `turn_angle = 360 / num_sides[i]`, you can append your list `turn_angles` with the result `turn_angles.append(turn_angle)`, so you can print it in a loop:

```
num_sides = [3, 4, 5, 6]

def compute_turn_angles():
    turn_angles = []
    for i in range(len(num_sides)):
        turn_angle = 360 / num_sides[i]
        turn_angles.append(turn_angle)
    return turn_angles

angles = compute_turn_angles()

for angle in angles:
    print(angle)
```

without appending the result to your list, you are just overwriting the last result in your list. `turn_angle` always only includes the last calculation `60`.

`print(turn_angle)` after `turn_angle = 360 / num_sides[i]` will also do the trick ;)